# Bot work perfect on emulator but not in any channel

Tags: skype, botframework

I wrote a bot using Bot Connector REST API from Microsoft Bot Framework and tested it via Bot Framework Emulator V3.5.25 on localhost and remotely with app id and app password, it work just perfect; but using Skype channel i can receive message on my endpoint but bot´s answer never reach to Skype user.

Incoming message from Skype user

```
{
    "text": "Hello bot?",
    "type": "message",
    "timestamp": "2017-03-03T19:08:30.988Z",
    "id": "1488568110992",
    "channelId": "skype",
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/",
    "from": {
        "id": "29:1rILOvqsAlldnM1C4nK30sdjpveZezKC9LX5yYAvyi_k",
        "name": "Skype User"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "29:1rILOvqsAlldnM1C4nK30sdjpveZezKC9LX5yYAvyi_k"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "28:e20620eb-b214-4b02-8de1-c7fd14c11005",
        "name": "My_bot"
    },
    "entities": [{
        "locale": "es-ES",
        "platform": "Windows",
        "type": "clientInfo"
    }]
}
```

Outgoing message from my bot

```
{
"type": "message",
"text": "Bot is Ok",
"replyToId": "1488568110992",
"locale": "es",
"channelId": "skype",
"serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/",
"from": {
    "id": "28:e20620eb-b214-4b02-8de1-c7fd14c11005",
    "name": "My_bot"
},
"conversation": {
    "id": "29:1rILOvqsAlldnM1C4nK30sdjpveZezKC9LX5yYAvyi_k"
},
"recipient": {
    "id": "29:1rILOvqsAlldnM1C4nK30sdjpveZezKC9LX5yYAvyi_k",
    "name": "Skype User"
}
}
```

I don't receive a json payload response from the Bot Framework just this status: **400 Bad Request**. Just for test purposes my bot sent a response with some missing parameters and the Bot Framework response with the same status and a json payload with an error message code and text.

I did not publish my bot, but according to Bot Framework docs, is not necessary.

I´m missing something? Anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is not required to be published for the skype bot to work. I'd like to suggest you few checkpoints and check if you have already tried them:

The Bot Framework Developer Portal contains a test panel where you can test the connection from the Bot Connector service to your bot. The security model used by the Bot Connector differs slightly from the security model used by the Emulator, and this is the most realistic step in testing your bot’s authentication.

Follow these steps to test your bot in the cloud with security enabled:
Make sure your bot is deployed and running

1. Log in to the Bot Framework Developer Portal, click on “My bots,” and if necessary, select the bot you want to debug from the list.
2. Locate the test panel in the bottom-left corner of the screen and click the blue “Test” button. The results of the test appear just below the button.
3. Please check the status of your bot on Skype Developer Portal.
4. If the bot has status Pending Review. It looks like that bot will not work while the status is in "Pending Review". Check this [screenshot](http://www.screencast.com/t/5SSSo6V5). 
   The bot is successfully registered only if it looks [like this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6tXaIQYccDwQUJWRmRMN1ZCemc) before publishing.

Let me know in details if you still have any issues.

Thanks

-Jyo

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply, I follow the step 1 and 2 from your post and test the Bot's connection, the result is: Endpoint authorization succeeded.

I can not find any Skype Developer Portal, every intent to get in [https://www.skype.com/en/developer/](https://www.skype.com/en/developer/), push me to bot framework developer portal.

In the bot framework developer portal, the bot status is: **In review**.

Thanks again

Comment: Can you please send me the snapshot of the bot status, you are talking about. So that I can get more clarity and help you.

Comment: Here you will see the Bot status and the bot connection test result [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B28bnDX_rAZvTFh6RlNiRUxHdlk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The registered bot is supposed to look like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6tXaIQYccDwQUJWRmRMN1ZCemc) if it is not published and if it is supposed to work through any channel. Though it is not required the bot to be registered to work on local emulator it is required to be registered to work through any channel. Probably this is the reason its not working. Can you please register a new bot and update those credentials in the bot and see if its working.

Comment: Can you please provide us your bot's handle or app ID so that we can investigate?

Comment: I registered a new bot [Add to Skype](https://join.skype.com/bot/342ece8e-21ea-4b52-aa6e-e464cd0a6463); the problem remains the same; when  registered the bot, I checked the bot issues and found a message like this: **There was a problem synchronizing your bot to Skype**, you can see it in this [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B28bnDX_rAZvLVFuT3JWSF9wRTg/view). Every intented through skype channel produce an issues with a message like **Internal server error**.

Comment: The bot should be hosted on any cloud services like Azure to be accessible through any channels or either published to directory. Please check this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1106457/An-Introduction-to-the-Microsoft-Bot-Framework)

Comment: My bot is hosted on a server which is administered by my team and has a valid SSL certificate. I don't want to make my bot endpoint public, but I can send the full URL by email.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the problem is solved.

The bearer scheme was in bad format, instead of Bearer, had bearer.

Changed that and everything work.

Really sorry.